# $scope binding in Angular

Tags: angularjs

If you have a controller what is the preferred method for data binding, multiple smaller ones or one big object e.g.:

```
$scope.username = 'John Doe';
$scope.email = 'me@me.com';
$scope.city = 'Amsterdam';
```

or

```
var user = {};
user.username = 'John Doe';
user.email = 'me@me.com';
user.city = 'Amsterdam';

$scope.user = user;
```

Comment: Use the second one. This will have advantages of prevention of digest bugs and IMO it's cleaner (your model is the user, not the scope)

Comment: The 'big' one makes it easier to have multiple users. But it may just be my preference. This question may be kind of opinion-based...

Comment: second one is preferable

Comment: What is the argument for the big one to be the preference? As I am wondering if on changes the whole object needs to be evaluated. Where with the small ones it is only the changed variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with second one, from angularjs wiki

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't
>   even need to know it is happening... until you try 2-way data binding
>   (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive (e.g., number, string,
>   boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope. It
>   doesn't work the way most people expect it should work. What happens
>   is that the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the
>   parent property of the same name. This is not something AngularJS is
>   doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works. New
>   AngularJS developers often do not realize that ng-repeat, ng-switch,
>   ng-view and ng-include all create new child scopes, so the problem
>   often shows up when these directives are involved. (See this example
>   for a quick illustration of the problem.)
>
> This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the
>   "best practice" of always have a '.' in your ng-models – watch 3
>   minutes worth. Misko demonstrates the primitive binding issue with
>   ng-switch.
>
> Having a '.' in your models will ensure that prototypal inheritance is
>   in play. So, use

```
<input type="text" ng-model="someObj.prop1"> rather than 
<input type="text" ng-model="prop1">.
```

> If you really want/need to use a primitive, there are two workarounds:
>
> Use $parent.parentScopeProperty in the child scope. This will prevent
>   the child scope from creating its own property. Define a function on
>   the parent scope, and call it from the child, passing the primitive
>   value up to the parent (not always possible)

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes